# Why are gradient-based methods better for nonstationary environments?

Tags: optimization, gradient-descent, stationarity, independent-component-analysis

In the book [Independent Component Analysis](https://www.cs.helsinki.fi/u/ahyvarin/papers/bookfinal_ICA.pdf) (Hyvärinen et al. 2001), it is mentioned on page 178:

> The advantage of such gradient methods, closely connected to learning in neural networks, is that the inputs $z(t)$ can be used in the algorithm at once, thus enabling fast adaptation in a nonstationary environment

What does this sentence mean and why are gradient-based methods superior in nonstationary environments in general?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's another interpretation: Suppose you're estimating $\theta_\star(T) = \text{argmin } f(\theta; T)$ where $f(\theta; T) = \frac{1}{T}\sum_{t=0}^T f_t(\theta)$. For example, let's suppose you're working with data that streams in every second or so; $\theta_\star(10)$ is your best estimate at time $T=10$ seconds after starting (using all observations up to that point), $\theta_\star(57)$ is best estimate at time $T=57$ seconds, and so forth.

Let's suppose right now it's time $T$. Instead of re-running your entire optimization at time $T+10$ (or any number of seconds later), you could simply wait 10 those ten seconds and adjust $\theta_\star(T)$ using batch gradient descent as follows:

$$\hat{\theta}_\star(T+10) = \theta_\star(T) - \eta \frac{1}{10}\sum_{t=T+1}^{T+10}\nabla f_t(\theta_\star(T))$$

where $\eta>0$ is your step size. This is really just stochastic/batch gradient descent with the new observations, known as filtering in the signal processing community. With the usual assumptions of SGD, your new best estimate is, in expectation, what you would have gotten if you reran the full optimization: $$\mathbb{E}(\hat{\theta}_\star(T+10)) = \theta_\star(T+10)$$ **Even more, if your parameter is not stationary, this approach may yield even better results than if you were to rerun the full optimization.** That is, $\hat{\theta}_\star(T+10)$ may lead to better prediction error than $\theta_\star(T+10)$.

I have [a paper where this is applied](https://mustafameisa.files.wordpress.com/2015/07/227cproj.pdf) to forecast prices data using Tweets, where both data sources are not evenly-spaced. Attached below is an image from said paper that demonstrates how the true non-stationary parameter can be "chased" by SGD updates, where the different variations are due to varying step sizes.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I think this sentence is somewhat confusing. At first glance, it appears to say that using the gradient is what lets an algorithm adapt quickly to nonstationary signals. But, this isn't true in general. Rather, I think the phrase "such gradient methods" refers to the online, gradient-based algorithm they just described in the previous section. And, it's online training that lets the algorithm adapt to nonstationary signals, rather than the fact that it's gradient-based.

Indeed, on the previous page they give a batch mode, gradient-based algorithm in equations 8.14, 8.15, then an online version in equations 8.16, 8.17. They say, "An on-line (or adaptive) version of this algorithm can be obtained as well...Then  every  observation $z(t)$ can be used in the algorithm at once." It seems they use the phrase "at once" to mean 'immediately', rather than 'simultaneously'.

Online algorithms can adapt to nonstationary signals because they update the parameters after each data point is processed. If the signal statistics change, the parameters will be updated to reflect this. In contrast, batch mode algorithms update parameters using all data points together. If all points are treated identically, this strategy won't be able to adapt to local regions of the signal with different statistics. But, one could imagine batch mode algorithms that work with nonstationary signals using some extra mechanism to account for this.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your explanation. Can you provide an example of a batch gradient descent algorithm that deals with nonstationary signals?